# Webpage is referencing the wrong path. What do I need to do to get it to reference the correct path

Tags: css

I have a gif file in a folder called imgs. When I load my HTML file I get the following error:

http://localhost:63342/AllFours/css/imgs/cardback.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

This is the reference in my CSS file: background-image: url("imgs/cardback.gif");

This is an image of my folder:

[image]

Comment: Where is your css file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSS file is on `~/AllFours/css/` and your imgs folder is on `~/AllFours/imgs/` use this to get an image:

```
url("../imgs/cardback.gif")
```